# Wi Fi keeps going on and off

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, linux-mint

I've got the following problem: my WiFi connection tends to turn off whenever it feels like it, and in order to restore it I have to reconnect, or to turn off WiFi generally for a number of seconds.

That only happens when I'm using my local connection, at other places everything works fine.

I've installed Wicd instead of the local network manager, but that seems to help only a bit.

Other laptops which share the same connection experience no problems or breakdowns.

.I'm running Mint 14 in HP dv6 laptop.

Comment: Are the drivers from the wireless distributer made for linux or did you have to use ndiswrapper?

Comment: I currently use the bcma module which came with Mint itself. All the attempts to install a proprietary wl driver from Broadcom (my chipset is Broadcom BCM4313) resulted in complete failure to detect any available networks at all

Comment: My guess is instantly driver since no one else is having problems. It could however just be your wireless card. Try seeing if anyone has a spare usb wireless adapter (that is known to be compatible with linux) you can borrow for 5 mins. If it works and doesn't drop we know it is one of these two things. However if it does well then that's a long complicated process. Or if know, for a fact, this driver works with that card with that machine more perfect than christens believe their "god" is, then your wireless card is broken.

Comment: I too am having this problem.  The wireless card disconnects and will not reconnect unless I uncheck then recheck "enable wifi".  I was able to bring it up by issuing an active scan also `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan essid YOUR_ESSID_HERE` though this is more or less hacking around the problem